# Is it possible to use "reduce" instead of for to set data to MapObject?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to remake and sort an array.
Is it possible to use "reduce" instead of "forEach" or "map"?
return beeProps.valueInfos.reduce (reduce()) would be great.

Anything else looks like it could be improved?

```
const makeTableArrayMap = (beeProps: beeOfProps) => {
    const rowMap: Map<number, beeOfValue[]> = new Map();

      beeProps.valueInfos.forEach((value, valueInfoIndex) => {
        Array.from(value.values).forEach(element => {
          const indexDate: number = element[0].getTime();
          const dateAndvalue: [
            Date,
            beeOfValue
          ][] = Array.from(value.values.entries());
          const newFateMap: Map<
            number,
            beeOfValue
          > = dateAndvalue.reduce((prev, current) => {
            return prev.set(current[0].getTime(), current[1]);
          }, new Map<number, beeOfValue>());
          // If rowMap includes date , bee will be added end of  beeOfValue. if not new array will be created and set.
          const bee:
            | beeOfValue
            | undefined = newFateMap.get(indexDate);
          if (bee) {
            if (rowMap.get(indexDate) !== undefined) {
              const tentativeArray:
                | beeOfValue[]
                | undefined = rowMap.get(indexDate);
              if (tentativeArray && tentativeArray.length > 0) {
                tentativeArray.push(bee);
                rowMap.set(indexDate, tentativeArray);
              }
            } else {
              rowMap.set(indexDate, [bee]);
            }
          }
        });
      });

    return rowMap;
  };

  type beeOfValue =
  | {
      kind: "on";
    }
  | {
      kind: "off";
    };
```

Comment: You might get more interest in the question if you make the title about what the code does and put the question that is currently the title into the body of this post. There are helpful hints on how to improve posts at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.